# Charged Particle in Magnetic Field

Tags: classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, potential-energy

For a charged particle in circular motion in a magnetic field, is there any potential energy involved?
If yes, how do we calculate it?
If no, i.e. the entire energy is kinetic, how do we know when there is potential energy involved in the total energy and when there is not?

Answer (score 1):

For a charged particle in circular motion in a magnetic field, it is not instructive to think in terms of energy conservation: the speed of the particle is a constant, so the kinetic energy $(1/2)\,m|\mathbf{v}|^2$ is a constant, so the potential energy of the charge (which you can certainly define with respect to any reference you'd like) is independent of position. Thus, the potential energy is trivial. Consequently, this approach does not give you the equations of motion.

More generally, the magnetic field does not contribute to a potential energy in the regular sense of writing a potential energy $V$ such that $$\ddot{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\mathbf{F}}{m}=-\frac{1}{m}\nabla V.$$

A potential function $V$ that would lead to the Lorentz $\mathbf{F}$ using the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#The_Lagrangian) is $$V=q(\phi-\dot{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\mathbf{A}),$$ where $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ (respectively) are defined such that the electric and magnetic fields satisfy $\mathbf{E}=\nabla\phi-\partial\mathbf{A}/\partial t$ and $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times \mathbf{A}$. However, this potential $V$ is not a physically measurable potential energy because it is gauge-dependent, i.e. there are multiple distinct vector fields $\mathbf{A}$ that may lead to a specified magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$, and although $\mathbf{B}$ is measurable, $\mathbf{A}$ is a mathematical tool (albeit a very powerful one).

Answer (score 0):

We talk about potential energy when there is a conservative force involved. The magnetic force ($\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times \vec{B})$ is actually a conservative force as the work done moving a particle between two points does not depend on the path (it is aslways zero as the force is always perpendicular to the velocity) and you can define a potential energy for the particle, but this energy is just constant in space because its variations between two points A and B are defined as the opposite of the work done in moving the particle from point A to point B (this definition works because it does not depend on the path).
But, this potential energy is not very useful (actually I am not totally sure it is correct to talk about potential energy for forces that do not depend only on position) because it does not give any information about the force itself. 
For instance, consider gravitational potenial energy; you know that the force associated to it depends only on the position, so, you can find the force on a particle by knowing its potential energy in all space ($\vec{F}=-\nabla U$). As this is a scalar quantity it could be easier to study a system by studying potential energy rather than the forces (which are vector quantities).

Comment: The magnetic force is not conservative. (a) The associated field is not conservative, and (b) you can't write the force as the gradient of a potential.

Answer (score 0):

There's potential momentum involved.  If $\vec{A}$ is the vector potential then $q\vec{A}$ is the potential momentum.  In classical mechanics for a single particle
$$E - q\phi = \frac{(\vec{p}-q\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{p}-q\vec{A})}{2m}$$
where $E$ is the total energy, $\vec{p}$ is the total momentum, $E - q\phi$ is the kinetic energy, $q\phi$ is the potential energy, $\vec{p}-q\vec{A}$ is the kinetic momentum and $q\vec{A}$ is the potential momentum.

In the relativistic case it's
$$(E - q\phi)^2 = (\vec{p}-q\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{p}-q\vec{A}) c^2 + m^2 c^4$$

Unfortunately, it's difficult to generalize this for multiple particles because of the need to include terms for interaction between them and the use of retarded time.

The gauge transformation of the four-potential $\phi, \vec{A}$ becomes a special case of a gauge transformation for a Lagrangian/Hamiltonian.